# Whats is "ANT patterns" in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver

I am working on Geo-server 2.16.x on Cent-OS & I have configured "auth-key" extension.
While configuring extension I used /**  "ANT patterns".

I don't know the meaning of ANT patterns, I simply copied default and re-named as 'api-key'

Could anyone tell me what is 'ANT patterns' ? And why they are required in Geo-server ?
[image]

My primary research says that it's related to Java Spring framework and related to security but it's great if anyone explains in simple language.

Answer (score 2):

I've always assumed (but never actually checked) they are the same format as [patterns](https://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html) in [Apache Ant](https://ant.apache.org/). In this case implemented by something like a Spring [`AntPathMatcher`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html).